# Android Parse Querying 2 Classes

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

So I have 2 classes:

```
Request class
| objectId | user | data | status |
```

and

```
User class
| objectId | fullName |
```

'user' key in `Request` is a `Relation<_User>` type which is a pointer to User class.

I want to get all Request where the `status` is `new` and I want to get the `fullName` of the user too.

The data that I want to get should look like this.

```
| objectId | user | data | status | fullName |
```

This is what I have tried based on [Parse.com Android Guide](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries-relational-queries)

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Request");
query.include("user");
query.whereEqualTo("status", "new");
```

This will return `null` in requests, but when I delete the `include` method, it shows the value but without the `fullName`.

Can anyone help? Please comment if my explanations aren't clear or if you need more information. Thank you :)

**EDIT**
This is how I insert new row in Request.

```
ParseObject post = new ParseObject("Request");
post.put("data", "data");
post.put("status", "new");
ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseRelation<ParseUser> relationRequest = post.getRelation("user");
relationRequest.add(user);
```

Comment: You don't have any foreign key to establish link between the data in two classes. Use foreign key concept

Comment: @Kat-hat I think I have added the relation correctly, please look at my edited post. I am also able to click on `View Relations` in the Parse Data in browser and view the User data. :)

Comment: Are you using Request class "user" to point the User class objectId?Does "user" contain objectId of string type?

Comment: You should use Pointer type column for user column in Request class instead of relation and @Kat-hat answer is perfect for your query then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to create `user1` column in `Request` class containing the `objectId` of `User` class.

**For creating `user1` column use**

```
ParseUser currentUser=ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
ParseObject post = new ParseObject("Request");
post.put("data", "data");
post.put("status", "new");
post.put("user1", currentUser);
post.saveInBackground();
```

And then use the below code to fetch **fullName** from `User` class.

```
 ParseQuery<ParseObject> getQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Request");
        getQuery.include("user1");
        getQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    if (scoreList != null && scoreList.size() > 0) {
                        ParseObject putData = scoreList.get(0);
                        String user1=putData.getParseObject("user1").getString("fullName");
                        String user2=putData.getString("user2");
                        Log.e("USer 1", ""+user1);
                        Log.e("USer 2", ""+user2);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

This is working for me. May help you too.